# Not able to center the image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a div, I want to center the image vertically and horizontally, tried different approaches like making container display as table and image as table-row etc.

Here it's not aligning vertically.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="container">
     <img src='images/img1.jpg' class="imgclass">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
    min-height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can add margin-left to get your image in centre.

Comment: You could also set the image as background of the div and center it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution would be to place the image as a background image inside the div

```
.container 
{
background:url('images/img1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
width: 70%;
min-height:400px;
}
```

You can also use the table inside the div and vertical and horizontal align the content of the table to center

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:center; text-align:center;">
<img src='images/img1.jpg' class="imgclass">
</td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `absolute` method:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqhsA/)

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  min-height:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

This way, you don't need to change the structure of your HTML and it will always be in the center, no matter what height or width you give the element, or even if you re-size the page.

You also don't have to know the size of the image.

## Browser Compatibility:

Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Mobile Safari, IE8-10.

Comment: This isn't really a "trick" is it? Its just using absolute positioning. But yeah, this is how I would do it.

Comment: No it's not a trick at all, it's just there as lack of a better word. @Ruddy :(

Comment: Maybe method would make more sense.

Comment: Agreed, thats a better word. +1 for changing that word! xD

Answer (score 1):

You can try absolute centering. Using this method, you don't have to alter your html or know the size of the image.

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  width: 70%;
  min-height:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.container img {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 margin:auto;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th9St/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimension of the image, then following css will work for you:

```
img {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    margin-top:calc(50% - 125px);
    margin-top:-moz-calc(50% - 125px); /*for mozilla
    margin-top: -webkit-calc(50% - 125px); /*for webkit browsers.

}
```

You don't need any special style for container. This is the list of compatible browsers: http://caniuse.com/calc

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/143/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution there are much better ones such as absolute positioning. Using calc will limit browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need ie9+ you can use transforms:

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  min-height:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

If you know the exact size of the image you can use negative margins instead of translate. The margins will be half the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Take another div inside of `.container` and place image inside of it. Then making `.container` div's css rule to `display:table` and `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` for inner div will do the trick.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-cont">
       <img src='http://fc08.deviantart.net/images3/i/2004/09/1/0/flower_eyes.jpg' class="imgclass">
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
    min-height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
    background:#ccc;
}

.img-cont{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v22rG/